# Cannot create an SSH tunnel to Zeppelin web display on aws, using Putty on windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, putty, aws-cli

The following instructions are given for the ec2 instance that I'm trying to connect to:

> To access your instance: Open an SSH client. (find out how to connect
>   using PuTTY)

CHECK!

> Locate your private key file (keypair.pem). The wizard automatically
>   detects the key you used to launch the instance.

I launched Putty with a .ppk and I also still have the .pem sitting on my local machine. However, how does this help once I am in the aws Linux terminal?
It sounds to me that the .pem should now be located on the remote machine, not my local one.

> Your key must not be publicly viewable for SSH to work. Use this
>   command if needed: chmod 400 keypair.pem

This is fine once the previous step is clearer.

> Connect to your instance using its Public DNS:
>   ec2-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
>
> Example: ssh -i "keypair.pem"
>   root@ec2-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

I am currently typing this in (also trying ec2-user instead of root) but I get the following:
*Warning: Identity file keypair.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).*

> Please note that in most cases the username above will be correct,
>   however please ensure that you read your AMI usage instructions to
>   ensure that the AMI owner has not changed the default AMI username.

In case this is important, what user name are they referring to here?

I have also made sure the I can SSH into the security group from all locations.

Comment: It sounds like you are already SSH'd into the instance, via Putty. Now you are looking at instructions on how to SSH into the instance via the `ssh` command and trying to run those commands to SSH into the instance, from inside the instance, that you are already SSH'd into. Pick a method of connecting to the instance, either `ssh` or `putty`.

Comment: After a few lessons, I have re-titled my question to more accurately reflect what my issue was.

Comment: This helped: https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/setup-ssh-tunneling-foxy-proxy-putty/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christopher, I am not sure if you have access to the AWS console, but If you do, then it will be easy to find out the correct user name of your EC2 machine. click on the check mark box to pick your instance, then click Connect, and it will show you the correct user name. If it is an amazon AMI image, it will most likely be ec2-user, other images can have root, ubuntu, bitnami, or any other user configured by the AMI creator.
Your error message: " Warning: Identity file keypair.pem not accessible" indicates an issue with your private key not being accessible.
You said you converted the .pem to ppk for putty, which will enable you to SSH via putty. If you need to SSH from an EC2 machine to another EC2 machine, you will need that private key with the "pem" extension. 
Think of your private key as your password, except that it's stored in a file.
ssh -i "keypair.pem" root@ec2-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
This command says: Log me in via SSH protocol to server xxxx.eu... using password file (Private key) "keypair.pem" that resides in the current directory.
if you do an "ls" and you don't see "keypair.pem" then that is your issue.
I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Cloudquiz. It seems that is indeed my issue, the .pem is missing from the current directory. Is there a way that I can send it there via the aws console or by uploading it from my local machine?

Comment: you can either FTP the file, but that's too much work to setup FTP, and open ports, etc... What I would do is create the file: sudo vi keypair.pem then copy and paste the content of your pem file. If you don't know how to do that in VI, use nano. First open the file in windows with notepad, copy the file, in the linux server create the file, type "i" to switch to insert mode, right click so that it will paste your clipboard content, ESC key to get out of insert mode, ":wq" to save the file. last is to change permissions on the file: sudo chmod 400 keypair.pem

Comment: Followed your steps and get the following:

debug1: Trying private key: keypair.pem
debug1: could not open key file 'keypair.pem': Permission denied
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).

So there seems to be a permission issue, which I'm guessing is related to the chmod function?

Comment: Two things were preventing me from accessing the Zeppelin instance on the cluster:
1) A conceptual misunderstanding (hence inaccurate title to question) that once ssh'ed into the cluster, I needed to turn my attention to setting up an ssh tunnel between the Zeppelin Instance on the cluster and my pc. This is outlined in the aws docs. 
2) This is the big one: Once in Putty, making sure that the source port and destination are set. In Putty: Connection->SSH->Tunnels.
Then setup FoxyProxy in Chrome with the same port and enter localhost:[source_port] in the browser worked.
Thanks @cloudquiz